# mysql select * from not in a table

Tags: mysql

```
select * from csclass where cnumber not in (
  (select distinct cnumber from temp where taken=0) union (select cnumber from    taken where username = "1")
);
```

This is what i have now. I just google it and realized that not in could not be a table. So how could i do this?

Thank you.

The below is my whole code.

```
create temporary table temp 
(cnumber VARCHAR(45) not null
, lclass VARCHAR(45) not null
,taken boolean not null default false
);

insert into temp(cnumber,lclass)
  select uclass,lclass from pre;


update temp,taken set temp.taken=true where temp.lclass=taken.cnumber;

select * from csclass where cnumber not in (
  (select distinct cnumber from temp where taken=0) union(select cnumber   from taken where username = "1")
);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you are asking. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Whats the issue?

Comment: What error are you getting? Show full error, not just `Error Code 1064. Syntax error`.

Answer (score 0):

So sorry for my bad English skill. So when i run this, there is error message: Error Code 1064. Syntax error.

So in the end i fixed this with below code:

```
select * from csclass where cnumber not in ( select cnumber from(

  (select distinct cnumber from temp where taken=0) union (select cnumber  from taken where username = "1")
) as total) ;
```

And Thank you guys.